# about "preprocessing" in PintOS compiling(C programming), There are 2-questions for referencing headers and incomplete type error

Tags: c, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor, virtual-memory, pintos

I'm student in practicing PintOS Project.
In Programming Project 3(Virtual Memory), I got ploblems about "preprocess in compiling" (C program).
I had tried all attempt that do my best, but I'm absolutely lost at this point on how to fix it.
Finally i come to here, had to ask you about this issue.

**error**

I finished stack growth part, so I am modifying `syscall.c` to implement `mmap`, but got problems in buid process. **the `spt` field is being recognized as an incomplete type and is not being excluded.**

**current situation**

The thread structure in question is declared in `thread.h`, and the type `supplemental_page_table` of spt, an element in the `thread` structure, is declared in `vm.h`. Above the thread structure in current thread.h
`#ifdef VM #include "vm/vm.h"` is preprocessing the format vm.h. I am currently using the EC2 server(ubuntu 18.04) via SSH connection to VS code, and have tried solutions such as make clean, make, inserting and changing the order of #include preprocessing and forward declaration code, and rebooting + reinstalling EC2, but there is no progress.

**Questions**

1. If `vm.h`, where the `spt` structure is declared in `thread.h`, is included before the thread structure, shouldn't it be able to be used without problems?

```
...
#ifdef VM            // I'm in project3(VM)
#include "vm/vm.h"

...

struct thread {
...
#ifdef VM
    /* Table for whole virtual memory owned by thread. */
    struct supplemental_page_table spt;      // The spt structure is defined in vm.h.
...
```

```
/* Print in terminal */
In file included from ../../include/userprog/process.h:4:0,
                 from ../../include/vm/vm.h:7,
                 from ../../vm/vm.c:4:
../../include/threads/thread.h:151:33: error: field ‘spt’ has incomplete type
  struct supplemental_page_table spt;
                                 ^~~
In file included from ../../vm/vm.c:4:0:
../../include/vm/vm.h:200:1: warning: "/*" within comment [-Wcomment]
 /* 현재 프로세스의 메모리 공간을 나타내는 구조체입니다.
  
../../vm/vm.c: In function ‘vm_init’:
../../vm/vm.c:21:23: warning: unused variable ‘start’ [-Wunused-variable]
     struct list_elem *start = list_begin(&frame_table);
                       ^~~~~
../../vm/vm.c: In function ‘vm_alloc_page_with_initializer’:
../../vm/vm.c:84:1: warning: label ‘err’ defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
 err:
 ^~~
../../vm/vm.c: In function ‘spt_insert_page’:
../../vm/vm.c:105:6: warning: unused variable ‘succ’ [-Wunused-variable]
  int succ = false;
      ^~~~
../../vm/vm.c: In function ‘spt_remove_page’:
../../vm/vm.c:111:55: warning: unused parameter ‘spt’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 void spt_remove_page (struct supplemental_page_table *spt, struct page *page) {
                                                       ^~~

...
```

2. Additionally, I have a customization called `tid_t` in `process.h` that is also defined in `thread.h`, and I've included it, but it doesn't reference it. I solved this problem by defining it again in process.h ,it is repeated, but I thought I'd ask along the same problem-context as above. For reference, I have the above issue after this.

```
/* Code in process.h */
#ifndef USERPROG_PROCESS_H
#define USERPROG_PROCESS_H

#include "threads/thread.h"

bool install_page (void *upage, void *kpage, bool writable);
// typedef int tid_t;       // If i remove annotation in this line, going to problem mentioned above

tid_t process_create_initd (const char *file_name);
tid_t process_fork (const char *name, struct intr_frame *if_);
int process_exec (void *f_name);
int process_wait (tid_t);
void process_exit (void);
void process_activate (struct thread *next);

#endif /* userprog/process.h */

/* Print */
In file included from ../../include/vm/vm.h:7:0,
                 from ../../include/threads/thread.h:12,
                 from ../../threads/init.c:24:
../../include/userprog/process.h:9:1: error: unknown type name ‘tid_t’; did you mean ‘size_t’?
 tid_t process_create_initd (const char *file_name);
 ^~~~~
 size_t
```

```
/* here is modified code i did, but i think it is not problem */

void *mmap (void *addr, size_t length, int writable, int fd, off_t offset) {
    if (offset % PGSIZE != 0) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (pg_round_down(addr) != addr || is_kernel_vaddr(addr) || addr == NULL || (long long)length <= 0)
        return NULL;
    
    if (fd == 0 || fd == 1) {
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    if (spt_find_page(&thread_current()->spt, addr))
        return NULL;

    struct file *target = find_file_by_fd(fd);
    if (target == NULL)
        return NULL;

    void * ret = do_mmap(addr, length, writable, target, offset);
    return ret;
}

void munmap (void *addr) {
    do_munmap(addr);
}

/* Do the mmap */
void *do_mmap (void *addr, size_t length, int writable, struct file *file, off_t offset) {
    struct file *mfile = file_reopen(file);

    void * ori_addr = addr;
    size_t read_bytes = length > file_length(file) ? file_length(file) : length;
    size_t zero_bytes = PGSIZE - read_bytes % PGSIZE;

    while (read_bytes > 0 || zero_bytes > 0) {
        size_t page_read_bytes = read_bytes < PGSIZE ? read_bytes : PGSIZE;
        size_t page_zero_bytes = PGSIZE - page_read_bytes;

        struct supplemental_page_table *spt = (struct supplemental_page_table*)malloc
                                        (sizeof(struct supplemental_page_table));
        spt->file = mfile;
        spt->offset = offset;
        spt->read_bytes = page_read_bytes;

        if (!vm_alloc_page_with_initializer (VM_FILE, addr, writable, lazy_load_segment, spt)) {
            return NULL;
        }
        read_bytes -= page_read_bytes;
        zero_bytes -= page_zero_bytes;
        addr       += PGSIZE;
        offset     += page_read_bytes;
    }
    return ori_addr;
}

/* Do the munmap */
void do_munmap (void *addr) {
    while (true) {
        struct page* page = spt_find_page(&thread_current()->spt, addr);
        
        if (page == NULL)
            break;

        struct supplemental_page_table * aux = (struct supplemental_page_table *) page->uninit.aux;
        
        // dirty(사용되었던) bit 체크
        if(pml4_is_dirty(thread_current()->pml4, page->va)) {
            file_write_at(aux->file, addr, aux->read_bytes, aux->offset);
            pml4_set_dirty (thread_current()->pml4, page->va, 0);
        }

        pml4_clear_page(thread_current()->pml4, page->va);
        addr += PGSIZE;
    }
}
```

[Here is my Team git-repository](https://github.com/KraftonJungle4th/Classroom5_Week10-11_Team3_PintOS/tree/DJ)
For now, we've saved this git in an intact (error-free) state, but we'll create a state with the same errors and push it soon.

`Thank you very much for your time!`

Comment: Thank you for your advice. We will try to fix it as soon as possible.

Comment: I've pushed to Git the most recent state in which the error occurs, and I've also fixed the error message that occurs in the current state to plain text format.
I tried to reproduce the situation you asked about, but I couldn't get it to revert back to that state.

Comment: Your error "error: field ‘spt’ has incomplete type" indicates that contrary to your belief, type `struct supplemental_page_table` is *not* defined in `vm/vm.h`, or you are *not* including that header.  Either one of those could be a function of which preprocessor macros are defined, and how, and where those definitions appear.

Comment: Removed the tag `compiler-errors` as it is not a compiler error only the error in **your** code

Comment: Solved it. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it!

The biggest problem that I didn't know what the problem was.
After asking around people, I learned that the problem is called a "**circular referenc**e" and "**duplicate header**" issues. In short, these are problems that occur when objects reference each other, or when headers are compiled with duplicate headers. There's a lot of reference on the internet, so use this as a milestone.

This could be solved by inserting **#pragma** once or **#ifndef HEADER_H #define HEADER_H #endif** syntax into the header.
In my case, I was able to solve it by inserting **the latter case**,#ifndef ..., and **#ifdef** into the header appropriately.
I leave the answer to myself for anyone else who encounters the same problem in the future.

good luck guys!